# Convert datetime in sequelize and express js to Bigint

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using Express js with sequelize and MySQL.For one of the field I'm using defaultValue:DataTypes.NOW which gives me 2015-08-08 14:13:23. I want to convert this field to BIGINT as 20150808141323. So is there any way in express I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string "20150808141323" by removing all characters that are not numbers:

```
"2015-08-08 14:13:23".replace(/[^\d]/g,"")  // => "20150808141323"
```

If you need an integer, you can just `parseInt(...)` that result(maximum integer in javascript is 2^53) although the convention when dealing with integer dates is to use [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score -1):

The date.getTime() method method used to returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970. when a new Date object is created it stores the date and time data when it is created. When the getTime() method is called on this date object it returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 (Unix Epoch).

```
var A = new Date('October 15, 1996 05:35:32'); 
var B = A.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OP isn't looking for epoch time. They wanted a string of the datetime timestamp concatenated together.